# How can run python on php?

Tags: php, python, html

I made a data input web page with a form.
And i want to run a python script on the server using the values from the web page and create an output file on the server.
Now I can input data and submit the web page. But then python script is not creating the output file on the server.

Below are my scripts.

First, I connect to index.php and input some text on the form and submit it

Below is index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="1test.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Secondly, 1test.php executes test.py using the form value on index.php.

Below is 1test.php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$cmd = "python test.py " . $name;
echo $cmd;
exec($cmd);
?>
```

my script work before python script. I can see $cmd value on web. But php can't execute python. python script has execute permission.
Lastly, the python script makes the file on the server. Form values will be array data on python.

Below is test.py

```
import sys
sip = sys.argv[1]
with open("doc.txt",'w') as f:
        f.write(sip)
f.close()
```

Comment: I tried using files full path. But is not work.

Comment: Which user owns the python script? Be wary of command injection, which would not be good. e.g: `Hello; rm ../ -rf`

Comment: python script owner is user. And that user can execute script on server directly

Comment: that question's answer is not work.

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors, like the output of `exec`…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to redirect errors from `stderr` to `stdin` with `2>&1` and capture the exit code:

```php
<?php

$name = $_GET['name'];
$cmd = escapeshellcmd("python test.py $name 2>&1");

echo "$cmd" . PHP_EOL;

exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);

echo "$return_var:" . PHP_EOL;
print_r($output);
```

The `$output` is an array of lines. If the script returns `0` (value of `$return_var`), it means success.

- [`exec()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.exec.php)
- [`escapeshellcmd()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.escapeshellcmd.php)